# Start wcf service right after host.open(), without having to wait for the solution to complete debugging

Tags: c#, wcf

Is there a way, I can start service at endpoint right after I call `host.open()`, without having to wait for the entire solution to debug. When I try to open the endpoint address right after `host.open()`, it keeps on loading, and right after I continue with the debugging and let it complete, the service shows up.

Comment: in visual studio go to your WCF project properties -> 'WCF' -> uncheck   'start when debugging another project'

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work.